# .htaccess perform redirect to a new domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have been working on a new site, and I need to use .htaccess to catch our maintence page and send it to our current website:

For example: mywebsite.net/shop_closed.html should redirect to www.mysite.com

I've tried using this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.hostname.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.oldsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and this catches everything. I'm just now learning about .htaccess today, and I'm not sure if I'm even in the ballpark with what I've been doing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your example doesn't seem to match what you specify. Have you tried skipping the RewriteCond and just use `RewriteRule ^shop_closed.html http://www.mysite.com [301,L]`?

Comment: Ah, I see. I Just tried what you suggested and it worked perfectly. SO i'm guessing the RewriteCond just told it that if it goes to website.hostname.net at all it would redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website\.hostname\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(shop_closed\.html)$ http://www.oldsite.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```